# how to use two mysql_query and two mysql_fetch_assoc in single code

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use following code. My goal is to display a page where id='$id'. However, if the value of $id is empty, i want to display latest entry in my database.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");
if(!(isset($_GET['id']))){ 
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name='somename' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
      while($var1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $y = $var1['id'];
      }
}
mysql_data_seek($query, 0);

$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : '$y';
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='$id'");
while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)){
//some code 
}
?>
```

problem is when $id has no value, first while loop is executed. But second while loop is not working. Some one please tell me a solution

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: thanks for advice...but what is the solution for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parenthesis around the first if statement

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){ 
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name='somename' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
      while($var1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $y = $var1['id'];
      }
}
```

Comment: sorry but problem still exists...and anyway what difference does it make??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
    mysql_select_db("database");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name='somename' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $var1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
    $y = $var1['id'];

    $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : $y ;
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='$id'");
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)){
     //some code 
    }
?>
```

Comment: why to use code inside 'if' statement if id has a value...that is why I created first mysql_query in 'if' statement. BTW problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Instead of

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='$id'");
```

Also, sanitize your data to avoid sql injection attacks and use PDO.

Comment: both the queries are same as far as i know and problem still exists.

Comment: They are not, I used backticks.